# Update solr schema.xml in real time for Solr 4.10.1

Tags: solr

I understand that in Solr 5.0, they provide a REST API to do real-time update of the schema using Curl. However, I could not do that for my eariler version of Solr 4.10.1.

Would like to check, is this function available for the earlier version of Solr, and is the curl syntax the same as Solr 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Solr Wiki, it's possible to request schema from Solr 4.2 and modify it starting from Solr 4.4

> In order to enable schema modifications via the Schema REST API, the
>   schema implementation must be declared as managed by Solr, that is,
>   not to be manually edited.
>
> Further, the schema must be configured as mutable in order to make
>   modifications to it.
>
> Both of these schema features (managed and mutable) are configured via
>   the  element in solrconfig.xml.

More information - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaRESTAPI